# Is there any way to get back database? MySQL is gone

Tags: mysql, windows

My windows 10 had a problem and I had to reset my windows to get rid of a blue screen problem. After resetting my windows there is no app installed also no file in 'program file' and 'programData' under c drive. Now any hope to get back the databases? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'reset my windows' what does that mean did you reinstall windows or reboot the computer?

Comment: Sounds like your best hope is a undelete tool that might find the database files on disk

Comment: Can you suggest me any one tool?

Comment: Yes it's can be called re installation. All personal files are ok but all of software are uninstalled.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Typically this would fit on SuperUser, but I'm not sure there's any solution you'll find there either...

Comment: Yes I have got a solution. I have recovered the folder named 'Data' by a recovery software.